# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) error

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I am new to the platform, so please point out if more info is needed.
I have configured Jenkins on 1 Linux Academy server and configured tomcat on another server as well as on Jenkins server also. 
When I am trying to build webapp.war on second tomcat server, it fails; whereas same settings work when I am trying to build on same machine where both Jenkins and Tomcat are deployed.
It throws error as:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tomcat_8/webapp/target/webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1841)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ****Connection timed out (Connection timed out)****
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

I have tried entering hostname as well as public IP in the Tomcat URL.
Where it is working, I am entering Tomcat URL as localhost:8090.
I have enabled firewall and enabled both port # 8080 and 8090 as well.
I am using credentails as deployer/deployer as u/n and password.
I even created 1 linux user as deployer and assigned password as deployer.
Have enabled my firewall and enabled ports 8080 and 8090 as well.

```
iptables-save | grep 8080 -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT 

iptables-save | grep 8090 -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Please suggest what else can be done.

Comment: what is the output of the command? pleas post it as formatted code...

Comment: @finder2: Thanks for your reply. I am able to resolve issue now by entering Private IP instead of Public IP in tomcat hostname